# How to highlight match string text in label

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel

I want to highlight match text in UILabel as [image]

Here's my code, but I do not know how to highlight each matched text with background color of yellow

```
//Highlight Text
let string = self.myInterestsLbl.text
if string?.range(of:"Fashion") != nil {
   print("Highlight Fashion")
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy Ermm, what I want is to change background color but not text color. Thanks!

Comment: OK, you can change any attribute you need. See the linked duplicates.

Comment: @rmaddy I found it by using NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, but the result was diffrent from what I want.

Comment: Now that you understand the basics of what you need to do, post a new question with specific details about your solution if needed.

Comment: @rmaddy ok, thank you for ur guidance :)